# Showing Error syntax error in php?

Tags: php

I Have Created php calculator site.i have issues my code.tried to solve my error. Trying to Run my code always getting error.even tried each echo statement. i not able find my mistake.. searched this error google tired many methods  no lucky.what mistake i did in my code ? thanks in advance

```
<div id="default_tab_pane1" style="display:visible">
<table width="100%">
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="left-top">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Regular Mortgage </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">About Your Loan </td>
    <td>About Your Payment </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="purchaseprice">Purchase Price $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["purchaseprice"],2)?></td>
    <td id="principleandinterest">Principle and Interest $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["_PI"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="downpmt">Down Payment $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["downpaymentamt"],2)?> </td>
    <td id="tax">Tax $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["tax"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="secondmortgage">Second  Mortgages $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["normalsecond"],2)?></td>
    <td id="miploaninsurance">MIP Loan Insurance $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["monthlymipamt"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="financedmip">Financed MIP Ins $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["upfrontmipamt"],2)?></td>
    <td id="hazardinsurance">Hazard Insurance $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["hazardinsurance"],2)?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="firstmortgage">1st Mortgage Total $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["firstmortgage"],2)?></td>
    <td id="floodinsurance">Flood Insurance $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["floodinsurance"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="totalhoas">Total HOAs $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["totalhoa"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="melloroos">Mello-Roos $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["mello_roos"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="others">Other $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["others"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView1(true,20)" <?php if ($calculationtype=="maxloan") echo " checked";?> />Max Loan</td>
    <td><input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView1(false,20)" <?php if ($calculationtype=="minpmt") echo " checked";?> />Min Pymt</td>
    <td id="totalpmt">Total Payment $<?echo round($arrFirstBox["totalpmt"],2)?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>

<?php
if ($arr1["silentexists"]==true){
?>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="right-top">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">With  First Time Home Buyer Silent Second Added </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">About Your Loan </td>
    <td>About Your Payment </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="ss_purchaseprice">Purchase Price $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["purchaseprice"],2)?></td>
    <td id="ss_principleandinterest">Principle and Interest $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["_PIWithSS"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="ss_downpmt">Down Payment $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["downpaymentamt"],2)?> </td>
    <td id="ss_tax">Tax $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["tax"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="ss_normalsecond">Second  Mortgages $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["normalsecond"],2)?></td>
    <td id="ss_miploaninsurance">MIP Loan Insurance $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["ssmonthlymipamt"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td colspan="2" id="ss_financedmip">Financed MIP Ins $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["ssupfrontmipamt"],2)?></td>
    <td id="ss_hazardinsurance">Hazard Insurance $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["hazardinsurance"],2)?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="ss_silentsecond">Silence Second Amount $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["silentsecond"],2)?></td>
    <td id="ss_floodinsurance">Flood Insurance $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["floodinsurance"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="ss_firstmortgage">1st Mortgage Total $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["firstmortgageWithSS"],2)?></td>
    <td id="ss_totalhoas">Total HOAs $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["totalhoa"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="ss_melloroos">Mello-Roos $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["mello_roos"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="ss_others">Other $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["others"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="ss_maxloan" type="radio" value="maxloan" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView2(true,20)" <?php if ($calculationtype=="maxloan") echo " checked";?> />Max Loan</td>
    <td><input name="ss_maxloan" type="radio" value="minpmt" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView2(false,20)"  <?php if ($calculationtype=="minpmt") echo " checked";?> />Min Pymt</td>
    <td id="ss_totalpmt">Total Payment $<?echo round($arrSecondBox["totalpmtwithSs"],2)?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
<? } ?>
</tr>

<tr><td>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="left-bottom">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">With  First Time Homebuyer MCC Credit Added</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">About Your Loan </td>
    <td>About Your Payment </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_purchaseprice">Purchase Price $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["purchaseprice"],2)?></td>
    <td id="mcc_principleandinterest">Principle and Interest $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["_PI"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_downpmt">Down Payment $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["downpaymentamt"],2)?> </td>
    <td id="mcc_tax">Tax $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["tax"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_normalsecond">Second  Mortgages $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["normalsecond"],2)?></td>
    <td id="mcc_miploaninsurance">MIP Loan Insurance $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["monthlymipamt"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_financedmip">Financed MIP Ins $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["upfrontmipamt"],2)?> </td>
    <td id="mcc_hazardinsurance">Hazard Insurance $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["hazardinsurance"],2)?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_firstmortgage">1st Mortgage Total $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["firstmortgage"],2)?></td>
    <td id="mcc_floodinsurance">Flood Insurance $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["floodinsurance"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="mcc_totalhoas">Total HOAs $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["totalhoas"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="mcc_melloroos">Mello-Roos $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["mello_roos"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td id="mcc_others">Other $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["others"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_purchaseprice">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td id="mcc_subtotal">Payment Subtotal $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["totalpmt"],2)?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="mcc_radioMaxLoan" type="radio" value="maxloan" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView3(false, 20);" id="mcc_radioMaxLoan1" <?php if ($calculationtype=="maxloan") echo " checked";?> />Max Loan</td>
    <td><input name="mcc_radioMaxLoan" type="radio" value="minpmt" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView3(false, 20);" id="mcc_radioMaxLoan2"  <?php if ($calculationtype=="minpmt") echo " checked";?> />Min Pymt</td>    
    <td id="mcc_mcc_credit">MCC Credit $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["mcc20pc"],2);?></td>
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="mcc_radioMCC" type="radio" value="15" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView3(false,15);"  id="mcc_radioMCC1" />15% MCC</td>
    <td><input name="mcc_radioMCC" type="radio" value="20" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView3(false, 20);" id="mcc_radioMCC2" checked />20% MCC</td>
    <td id="mcc_net_effective">Net Effective Payment $<?echo round($arrThirdBox["neteff20pc"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
</table><!--left bottom table-->
</td>
<?php if ($arr1["silentexists"]==true){?>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="left-bottom">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">With  First Time Homebuyer MCC Credit and Silent Second Added</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">About Your Loan </td>
    <td>About Your Payment </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_ss_purchaseprice">Purchase Price $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["purchaseprice"],2)?></td>
    <td id="mcc_ss_principleandinterest">Principle and Interest $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["_PIWithSS"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_ss_downpmt">Down Payment $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["downpaymentamt"],2)?> </td>
    <td id="mcc_ss_tax">Tax $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["tax"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_ss_normalsecond">Second  Mortgages $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["normalsecond"],2)?></td>
    <td id="mcc_ss_miploaninsurance">MIP Loan Insurance $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["ssmonthlymipamt"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_ss_financedmip">Financed MIP Ins $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["ssupfrontmipamt"],2)?> </td>
    <td id="mcc_ss_hazardinsurance">Hazard Insurance $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["hazardinsurance"],2)?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_ss_silentsecond">Silence Second Amount $<?echo round($arr2["silentsecond"],2)?></td>
    <td id="mcc_ss_floodinsurance">Flood Insurance $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["floodinsurance"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_ss_firstmortgage">1st Mortgage Total $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["firstmortgageWithSS"],2)?></td>
    <td id="mcc_ss_totalhoas">Total HOAs $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["totalhoas"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="mcc_ss_melloroos">Mello-Roos $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["mello_roos"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td id="mcc_ss_others">Other $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["others"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="mcc_ss_purchaseprice">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td id="mcc_ss_subtotal">Payment Subtotal $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["totalpmtwithSs"],2)?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="mcc_ss_radioMaxLoan" type="radio" value="maxloan" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView4(false, 20);" id="mcc_ss_radioMaxLoan1" <?php if ($calculationtype=="maxloan") echo " checked";?> />Max Loan</td>
    <td><input name="mcc_ss_radioMaxLoan" type="radio" value="minpmt" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView4(false, 20);" id="mcc_ss_radioMaxLoan2" <?php if ($calculationtype=="minpmt") echo " checked";?> />Min Pymt</td>    
    <td id="mcc_ss_mcc_credit">MCC Credit $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["mccss20pc"],2);?></td>
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="mcc_ss_radioMCC" type="radio" value="15" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView4(false,15);" id="mcc_ss_radioMCC1" />15% MCC</td>
    <td><input name="mcc_ss_radioMCC" type="radio" value="20" onClick="javascript:toggleLoanView4(false, 20);" id="mcc_ss_radioMCC2" checked />20% MCC</td>
    <td id="mcc_ss_net_effective">Net Effective Payment $<?echo round($arrFourthBox["neteffss20pc"],2)?> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
<?}?>
</tr>
</table> <!--main table-->
</div><!-- tab-->
```

Comment: Please tell us what the error is, what happened that you didn't expect, and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\xampp\htdocs\DonCalculator\default_results.php on line 678 this error getting

Comment: Have u checked all syntexes.

Comment: yes brother still getting

Comment: this error usually comes, when curly braces - {} are not closed properly.

Comment: Please post the full file (default_results.php) which you are getting the error for. The code you posted isn't even 678 lines long.

Comment: i get error  this  code only sir i have checked previous code its working

Comment: Check once again for array values OR add static values and check this code is getting error ?

Comment: ok sure brother i will check brother

Comment: i find the issues code   <?php if ($arr1["silentexists"]==true){?>